# What common programming mistakes can cause stuck CLOSE_WAIT in epoll edge triggered mode?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, epoll

I'm wondering what common programming situations/bugs might cause a server process I have enter into CLOSE_WAIT but not actually close the socket.

What I'm wanting to do is trigger this situation so that I can fix it.  In a normal development environment I've not been able to trigger it, but the same code used on a live server is occasionally getting them so that after many many days we have hundreds of them.

Googling for close_wait and it actually seems to be a very common problem, even in mature and supposedly well written services like nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CLOSE_WAIT` is basically when the remote end shut down the socket but the local application has not yet invoked a `close()` on it. This is usually happens when you are *not* expecting to read data from the socket and thus aren't watching it for readability.

Many applications for convenience sake will always monitor a socket for readability to detect a close.

A scenario to try out is this:

1. Peer sends 2k of data and immediately closes the data
2. Your socket is then registered with epoll and gets a notification for readability
3. Your application only reads 1k of data
4. You stop monitoring the socket for readability
5. (I'm not sure if edge-triggered epoll will end up delivering the shutdown event as a separate event).

See also:

(from `man epoll_ctl`)

> EPOLLRDHUP (since Linux 2.6.17)
>             Stream socket peer closed connection, or shut down writing half of connection.  (This flag is especially useful for writing
>   simple code
>             to detect peer shutdown when using Edge Triggered monitoring.)